# SQL: Where Field OR Field2 LIKE %entry%

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an easier/more efficient way of doing the following WHERE conditions:

```
WHERE (Field LIKE %entry% OR Field2 LIKE %entry%)
AND (Field LIKE %entry2% OR Field2 LIKE %entry2%)
```

Comment: I am guessing that "entry" and "entry2" are arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer following [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) as well:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(filed, field2) AGAINST ('entry' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (Field LIKE %entry2% OR Field2 LIKE %entry2%)
```

this part is a part of

```
(Field LIKE %entry% OR Field2 LIKE %entry%)
```

You can omit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
where concat_ws(' ', field1, field2) like '%entry%' and
      concat_ws(' ', field1, field2) like '%entry2%'
```

The performance should be about the same.

If you want to improve performance, consider full text text.